# HelloWorld User Control tutorial

Tags: user-controls, genexus

I'm doing the "Hello World" tutorial about User Control but without success.

In the first attempt I did the User Control like is shown in the tutorial page http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Hello+World+User+Control

But it didn't work, so I download the finished user control available for download in the end of the tutorial.

With the download user control, I have created this web panel
[image]

with this event

[image]

But I have an empty result
[image]

What is missing here? Any tips for debugging here?

I'm using the GeneXus latest version, GeneXus X Evolution 3 (trial).

**Edit:** 
The user control code:

```
function HelloWorld($)
{
    this.Width;
    this.Height;
    this.FontFace;
    this.FontColor;
    this.FontSize;

    this.show = function()
    {
        ///UserCodeRegionStart:[show] (do not remove this comment.)
        var buffer= '<a id="hworld1" href="#" style="color:rgb(' + this.FontColor.R + ',' + this.FontColor.G + ',' + this.FontColor.B + ')' + '; font-family:' + this.FontFace+ ';font-size:' + this.FontSize + 'pt;">Hello World!!!</a>';          

        this.setHtml(buffer);                       

        document.getElementById("hworld1").onclick = this.HelloWorldClicked;        

        ///UserCodeRegionEnd: (do not remove this comment.)
    }
    ///UserCodeRegionStart:[User Functions] (do not remove this comment.)

    ///UserCodeRegionEnd: (do not remove this comment.):
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the show method in the js file is being invoked?

Comment: It was a big mistake not having started to go see the console.
As soon as the browser open I get this error:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://trialapps3.genexus.com/Idf92d5b5d4d440bb6389f30e202ac93d5/gxmetadata/sdapps.json?0.8899557499680668`

Comment: When I open the panel I get this one:
`GET http://trialapps3.genexus.com/Idf92d5b5d4d440bb6389f30e202ac93d5/HelloWorldv3/HelloWorldRender.js 404 (Not Found) `

Comment: But the HelloWorldRender.js is in the same directory of HelloWorld.control and HelloWorldIcon.ico that GeneXus recognize. Do you know why this happens? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the HelloWorld tutorial it says:
_6) Close GeneXus (if opened) and run "Genexus.exe /install" under the GeneXus installation directory. Then start GeneXus as usual._

    
But I don't know how to do the step: "_run "Genexus.exe /install" under the GeneXus installation directory_". ??

Comment: After I run in cmd line the command:
`"C:\Program Files <x86>\Artech\GeneXus\GeneXusXEv3Trial\Genexus.exe" /install` 
It is now working!

Comment: @Fede after changes in the javascript of the user control, what are the steps to see those changes applied? Because I change the "Hello World" string but I always get the "Hello World", even if I clean the cache of the browser, and even if I close genexus and run the install command again! I don't really know why the text never change after I change the javascript code.

Comment: I've read a lot about user controls in the wiki, but I do not understand why after changing the js code, the changes never happen when I use the use control after the changes!
I have a diagram tool developed in Javascript and I'm trying to use that in a genexus web application, but I'm stuck with this little "problems" doing this simple user control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I run in cmd line the command:

```
"C:\Program Files <x86>\Artech\GeneXus\GeneXusXEv3Trial\Genexus.exe" /install
```

It is now working! It was not clear for me, this step in the tutorial.

**Edit:**

I have found this in the wiki, that explains better how to install an User Control, and solves the problem I had:

> Manual installation
>
> 1. Download the control from GeneXus Marketplace.
> 2. Unzip files
> 3. Copy the directory under the UserControls directory in the GeneXus installation.
> 4. Execute GeneXus with the /install parameter. For example: GX_Installation_Path\GeneXus.exe /install
> 5. Check that the toolbox has added the new option under the User Controls section.
> 6. Enjoy!